# BMI calculator in python: too many if statements how to reduce that?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm very new in programming and have started to learn python. I wrote my first own BMI calculator in python and somehow I'm not really satisfied with my code. I guess I have too many if statements in my code and want to know how to reduce that? Can you give me some advice or suggestions how to make that script better and dynamic?

Kind regards!!

```
gender = input("Are you a male(m) or female(f): ")
age = int(input("How old are you: "))
weight = float(input("How much do you weigh in kilograms?: "))
height = float(input("What is your height in centimeters: "))


bmi = round(weight / ((height/100) ** 2))

if bmi in range(19, 24) and age in range(19, 24):
    print("Your BMI is optimal for your age!")
elif bmi in range(25, 34) and age in range(20, 25):
    print("Your BMI is optimal for your age!")
elif bmi in range(35, 44) and age in range(21, 26):
    print("Your BMI is optimal for your age!")
elif bmi in range(45, 54) and age in range(22, 27):
    print("Your BMI is optimal for your age!")
elif bmi in range(55, 64) and age in range(23, 28):
    print("Your BMI is optimal for your age!")
elif bmi >= 65 and age in range(24, 29):
    print("Your BMI is optimal for your age!")
else:
    print("Your BMI is not okay for your age!!!")

if bmi < 20 and gender == "m":
    print("Your BMI is",str(bmi)+". That means underweight")
elif bmi < 19 and gender == "f":
    print("Your BMI is",str(bmi)+". That means underweight")
elif bmi in range(20, 25) and gender == "m":
    print("Your BMI is",str(bmi)+". That means normal weight")
elif bmi in range(19, 24) and gender == "f":
    print("Your BMI is",str(bmi)+". That means normal weight")
elif bmi in range(26, 30) and gender == "m":
    print("Your BMI is",str(bmi)+". That means overweight")
elif bmi in range(25, 30) and gender == "f":
    print("Your BMI is",str(bmi)+". That means overweight")
elif bmi in range(31, 40) and gender == "m":
    print("Your BMI is",str(bmi)+". That means obesity")
elif bmi in range(31, 40) and gender == "f":
    print("Your BMI is",str(bmi)+". That means obesity")
elif bmi > 40 and gender == "m":
    print("Your BMI is",str(bmi)+". That means strong obesity")
elif bmi > 40 and gender == "f":
    print("Your BMI is",str(bmi)+". That means strong obesity")
else:
    print("Your BMI is",bmi)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are 2 issues here:

1. Performance, i.e. how efficiently the algorithm performs for large number of inputs.
2. Readability and maintainability.

Since your program only looks at one set of inputs, I am only going to consider the second of these.

The first section of your code can be written in much simpler fashion:

```
bmi = weight / ((height/100) ** 2)

optimal_bmi_age = [((19, 24), (19, 24)), ((25, 34), (20, 25)), ((35, 44), (21, 26)),
                   ((45, 54), (22, 27)), ((55, 64), (23, 28)), ((65, 1000), (24, 29))]

for ((bmi_min, bmi_max), (age_min, age_max)) in optimal_bmi_age:
    if (bmi_min <= bmi <= bmi_max) and (age_min <= age <= age_max):
        print('Your BMI is optimal for your age!')
        break
else:
    print('Your BMI is not okay for your age!!!')
```

Notice what we have done here. We separate *parameters*, i.e. boundaries for optimal BMI / age, from *logic*, i.e. a `for` / `else` loop and `if` statement. This process can be applied throughout your code. This will improve both readability and maintenance, should your parameters change.

If performance / optimisation is the main concern, see [@DavidScarlett's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48857843/9209546). That solution also implements a similar idea of separating parameters and logic.

Answer (score 2):

Ok, there's a lot to be improved here.

- There's no validation on the gender input, so an unrecognised value could be entered, although this does seem to be handled in the final else case, where only the BMI, with no explanation, is printed.
- `if bmi in range(19, 24)` means "if bmi has one of the values 19, 20, 21, 22, 23". So not only will this fail if bmi is 24, but it's terribly inefficient, and will break if you ever decide to change to float values for BMI. It would be far better to use greater than and less than to check whether a value is within a range.
- You've got `age` and `bmi` swapped around in your if statements. `if bmi >= 65 and age in range(24, 29)` suggests that it is optimal for a 25 year old to have a BMI of at least 65!
- No handling of ages less than 19. They will always be told their BMI is not optimal.
- All those repeated print statements that do the same thing. A quick improvement would be to instead set a Boolean variable, named "is_bmi_optimal" or similar, in the if cases, and then at the end have a single `if is_bmi_optimal` which does the printing.

As for your actual question of how to reduce the number of if statements, you'd need to replace them with some way of defining the age ranges and corresponding bmi ranges in data structures, and then iterating over them.

Here's a way of using the [bisect](https://docs.python.org/3/library/bisect.html) module to to that. Bisect is intended for maintaining lists in sorted order, but it can also be used to search a sorted list to find where a new value would fit, maintaining the sorted order. This means it can be used to find where in a series of ranges a value fits by defining those ranges as a list of the minimum value for each range. So your age ranges 19-24, 25-35, 35-44, 45-54, 55-64, 65+ would be represented as a list [25, 35, 45, 55, 65], and `bisect.bisect_left` would tell us where any age fits within that list as a value from `0` (less than 25) to `5` (65 or greater).

```
import bisect

gender = input("Are you a male(m) or female(f): ")
age = int(input("How old are you: "))
weight = float(input("How much do you weigh in kilograms?: "))
height = float(input("What is your height in centimeters: "))

bmi = round(weight / ((height/100) ** 2))

if age < 19:
    print("You're too young for this and I'm concerned you may be at risk of developing an eating disorder.")
    exit()

optimal_bmi_range_min_ages = [25, 35, 45, 55, 65]
optimal_bmi_ranges = [(19, 24), (20, 25), (21, 26), (22, 27), (23, 28), (24, 29)]
optimal_bmi_range = optimal_bmi_ranges[bisect.bisect_left(optimal_bmi_range_min_ages, age)]

if bmi >= optimal_bmi_range[0] and bmi <= optimal_bmi_range[1]:
    print("Your BMI is optimal for your age!")
else:
    print("Your BMI is not okay for your age!!!")

bmi_categories = ["underweight", "normal weight", "overweight", "obesity", "strong obesity"]
if gender == "m":
    bmi_cat_thresholds = [20, 26, 31, 41]
elif gender == "f":
    bmi_cat_thresholds = [19, 25, 31, 41]
else:
    print("Your BMI is",bmi)
    exit()

bmi_category = bmi_categories[bisect.bisect_left(bmi_cat_thresholds,bmi)]
print("Your BMI is " + str(bmi) + ". That means " + bmi_category)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
bmiheight=self.heightcm.get()
      print(bmiheight)
      bmiweight=self.weightkg.get()
      bmi= float((bmiweight)/((bmiheight / 100)**2))
      self.bmi = bmi
      print(bmi)
      self.label1=Label(self.master,text='Your BMI is %.2f' % bmi).grid(row=5,column=0)

      if bmi <= 18.5:
           self.label2=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the underweight group.',fg='blue').grid(row=6,column=0)
           totalindex = 'underweight'
           self.totalindex = totalindex
      elif bmi >18.5 and bmi <25:
           self.label3=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the healthy weight group.',fg='green').grid(row=6,column=0)
           totalindex = 'healthy'
           self.totalindex = totalindex
      elif bmi >= 25 and bmi < 30:
           self.label4=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the overweight group.',fg='orange').grid(row=6,column=0)
           totalindex = 'overweight'
           self.totalindex = totalindex
      elif bmi >=30:
           self.label5=Label(self.master,text='This places you in the obese group.',fg='red').grid(row=6,column=0)
           totalindex = 'obese'
           self.totalindex = totalindex

      if bmi >0 and bmi <999999999999999999999:
           self.button6=Button(self.master,text="Store Data",fg='red',command=self.dynamic_data_entry).grid(row=8,column=0)
```