# BMI Calculator with Arrays and for Loops, getting TypeError

Tags: python, typeerror

I'm trying to build a BMI calculator for a project. It must prompt the user to enter the height and weight of 6 members (the elements in the array), calculate the input and print the BMI of each member.  I've got that part taken care of, but I'm stumbling on the part where we use that to populate a second array and count the number of individuals that are underweight, overweight, or normal weight.  Here is what I have so far:

```
Names = ["Jim", "Josh", "Ralph", "Amber", "Chris", "Lynn"]
Hs = []
Ws = []

UW = 18.5
OW = 25

for Name in Names:
  Hs.append(int(input("What is your height in inches, " + Name + ": ")))
  Ws.append(int(input("What is your weight in pounds, " + Name + ": ")))

def BMI(Ws, Hs):
  for W, H in zip(Ws, Hs):
    bmi_total = (W * 703) / (H ** 2)
  for Name in Names:
    print("The BMI for " + Name + " is: ", bmi_total)

BMI(Ws, Hs)


BMIScore = [bmi_total]


countUW = 0
countHW = 0
countOW = 0

for i in BMIScore:
  if i <= UW:
    countUW = countUW + 1
  print("There are ", countUW, "underweight individuals.")
      
if i > UW and i < OW:
  countHW = countHW + 1
print("There are ", countHW, "individuals with a healthy weight.")
          
if i >= OW:
  countOW = countOW + 1
print("There are ", countOW, "overweight inividuals.")
```

And here is the output I get:

```
What is your height in inches, Jim: 5
What is your weight in pounds, Jim: 5
What is your height in inches, Josh: 5
What is your weight in pounds, Josh: 5
What is your height in inches, Ralph: 5
What is your weight in pounds, Ralph: 5
What is your height in inches, Amber: 5
What is your weight in pounds, Amber: 5
What is your height in inches, Chris: 5
What is your weight in pounds, Chris: 5
What is your height in inches, Lynn: 5
What is your weight in pounds, Lynn: 5
The BMI for Jim is:  140.6
The BMI for Josh is:  140.6
The BMI for Ralph is:  140.6
The BMI for Amber is:  140.6
The BMI for Chris is:  140.6
The BMI for Lynn is:  140.6
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Crase\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\Final Project.py", line 30, in <module>
    if i <= UW:
TypeError: '<=' not supported between instances of 'tuple' and 'float'
```

Additionally, is there a way to add whether a particular individual from the array is overweight or underweight in the line "print("The BMI for " + Name + " is: ", bmi_total)" ?

Any assistance would be appreciated.  And please pardon me if my presentation is a bit sloppy.  It's my first time posting.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [BMI calculator in python: too many if statements how to reduce that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48857564/bmi-calculator-in-python-too-many-if-statements-how-to-reduce-that)

Answer (score 1):

If you can't use an object-oriented approach, you can use lists of tuples to represent a person:

```py
names = ["Jim", "Josh", "Ralph", "Amber", "Chris", "Lynn"]
people = []

for name in names:
    height = int(input("What is your height in inches, " + name + ": "))
    weight = int(input("What is your weight in pounds, " + name + ": "))

    # Calculate the BMI while iterating over the list of names
    bmi = (weight * 703) / (height ** 2)

    people.append((name, height, weight, bmi))
```

Then, you can use a dictionary to store the overs, healthies and unders:

```py
UW_LIM = 18.5
OW_LIM = 25

stats = {"OW": 0, "HW": 0, "UW": 0}
for name, _, _, bmi in people:
    print("The BMI for", name, "is", bmi)
    key = "UW" if (bmi < UW_LIM) else "HW" if (UW_LIM < bmi < OW_LIM) else "OW"
    stats[key] += 1
```

Finally, just print 'em out:

```py
print("There are", stats["UW"], "underweight individuals.")
print("There are", stats["HW"], "individuals with a healthy weight.")
print("There are", stats["OW"], "overweight inividuals.")
```

---

For fun, here's an OOP approach:

```py
class Person:
    def __init__(self, name: str, height: float, weight: float):
        self.name = name
        self.height = height
        self.weight = weight

    @property
    def bmi(self):
        return (self.weight * 703) / (self.height ** 2)

    @property
    def classification(self):
        return 0 if (bmi < UW_LIM) else 1 if (UW_LIM < bmi < OW_LIM) else 2


names = ["Jim", "Josh", "Ralph", "Amber", "Chris", "Lynn"]

#        UW  HW  OW
stats = [ 0,  0,  0]

for name in names:
    height = int(input("What is your height in inches, " + name + ": "))
    weight = int(input("What is your weight in pounds, " + name + ": "))
    person = Person(name, height, weight)
    
    print("The BMI for", person.name, "is", person.bmi)

    stats[person.classification] += 1

print("There are", stats[0], "underweight individuals.")
print("There are", stats[1], "individuals with a healthy weight.")
print("There are", stats[2], "overweight inividuals.")
```

Answer (score 0):

Answering the first question you might want to try changing `i` into `float(i)`. I'm not sure this will work with all of the loops, but you need to define the type of variable "i" is. And to answer the second question, can you could provide more information about what "overweight" and "underweight" is, but you could add a statement like this:

```
if bmi_total <= 150:
    #etc.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bmi_total is defined within your BMI function but then used outside of it.  The error I got when trying your code specifically pointed to that.  To solve that you could make bmi_total a global so it is accessible outside of the function like this:

```
Names = ["Jim", "Josh", "Ralph", "Amber", "Chris", "Lynn"]
Hs = []
Ws = []

UW = 18.5
OW = 25

for Name in Names:
  Hs.append(int(input("What is your height in inches, " + Name + ": ")))
  Ws.append(int(input("What is your weight in pounds, " + Name + ": ")))

def BMI(Ws, Hs):
  for W, H in zip(Ws, Hs):
    # changed bmi_total to be a global variable here
    global bmi_total
    bmi_total = (W * 703) / (H ** 2)
  for Name in Names:
    print("The BMI for " + Name + " is: ", bmi_total)

BMI(Ws, Hs)

BMIScore = [bmi_total]

countUW = 0
countHW = 0
countOW = 0

for i in BMIScore:
  if i <= UW:
    countUW = countUW + 1
  print("There are ", countUW, "underweight individuals.")
      
if i > UW and i < OW:
  countHW = countHW + 1
print("There are ", countHW, "individuals with a healthy weight.")
          
if i >= OW:
  countOW = countOW + 1
print("There are ", countOW, "overweight inividuals.")
```

However, it would be better form to have the BMI function calculate the BMI and return that.  Most programmers are either directly or indirectly fans of the KISS (Keep It Stupid Simple) principle.  Basically, seperate each chunk of functionality into a logical function (like BMI()) and have it do one thing and one thing only (in this case, calculate the BMI).

As others have stated, you will also probably want to group your names, weights, heights, and BMI for each person into a container to keep things more organized.  That could be a list of lists, a dictionary, a class, or any number of other ways of keeping associated information together.  Great start though!

Comment: I appreciate the assistance, but when I try it with your change, the BMI print out is always the same for all named elements in the array.  It calculates the last height and weight values entered and assigns that value six times.

Comment: Do you happen to know how to amend the code so that it displays each individual BMI calculation?  I'm having trouble with that.

Comment: bmi_total is a single variable.  You are setting it each time through your for loop.  That means the last time through your for loop is the last time it is overwritten and the only value that is still stored in it.

If you want bmi_total to hold more than one value then it needs to be a tuple, list, set, dict, or some other container type of variable.

Comment: Alternatively, you could move all BMI calculations into the for loop that iterates over the names.  That way when you calculate the BMI and print it out it is always for the current name.

Comment: It appears your question was closed.  I'll add a couple more suggestions for how I would handle this.  Put JUST the BMI calculation into a function that ONLY returns the BMI.  Set the names as keys in a dict whose values are containers containing their height, weight, and BMI.  As you ask for each person's height and weight, you can then store it into the dict under their own key.  For example, Name["Jim"]["height"]=int(input("Please enter your height in inches: "))

That way all of your information is correctly grouped and easier to conceptualize for both the program and you.